# What is up with my actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, event-listener

I am trying to write a Event listener and function to output my text from my associative array whenever a button is clicked. I think I'm relatively close to how it should be but I am having trouble with the function part. My teacher gave us a guide and it's different than what we worked on in class so it has me pretty confused.

Here is my code

```
//Associative array with an indexed array
//Array constructor:
var desserts:Array = new Array();
//Format:
//array titleNoSpaces
desserts["PistachioFluffFruitSalad"] = ["Pistachio Fluff Fruit Salad", "1 can Crushed              pineapple with juice", "1 package Instant pistachio pudding mix", "1 container Whipped topping, thawed", "2 bananas, sliced", "2 cups mini marshmallows", "1 can fruit cocktail, drained", "1 can mandarin oranges, drained" ];
desserts["CoconutCreamPieIV"] = ["Coconut Cream Pie IV", "3/4 cup White Sugar", "1/4 cup Cornstarch", "1/4 tsp Salt", "2 cups Milk", "3 Egg Yolks", "2 tbsp Butter", "1 tsp Vanilla Extract", "1 cup Flaked Coconut", "1 Pie Shell, baked", "3 Egg Whites", "6 tbsp White Sugar" ];
desserts["EasySugarCookies"] = ["Easy Sugar Cookies", "2 and 3/4 cups All-purpose Flour", "1 tsp Baking Soda", "1/2 tsp Baking Powder", "1 cup Butter, Softened", "1 and 1/2 cups White Sugar", "1 Egg", "1 tsp Vanilla Extract" ];
desserts["ChocolateMeringuePie"] = ["Chocolate Meringue Pie", "1 Pie crust, baked", "1 cup White Sugar", "2 tbsp Unsweetened Cocoa Powder", "2 tbsp All-Purpose Flour", "1 pinch salt", "2 Eggs, separated", "1 cup Milk", "1 tbsp Butter", "1 tsp Vanilla Extract", "1/4 cup White Sugar"];
desserts["SweetAndSaltyCaramelApples"] =["Sweet and Salty Caramel Apples", "6 Granny Smith Apples", "6 Wooden Sticks", "1 package Individually wrapped caramels, unwrapped", "2 tbsp water", "1/2 tsp Vanilla Extract", "1 1/2 tbsp coarse sea salt", "1 cup Semisweet Chocolate Chips"]; 

//Output data:
//  |--Dynamic text field instance name
//  |                 array titleNoSpaces   ingredient's index number
text_headline.text = desserts.PistachioFluffFruitSalad[0];
text_headline.text = desserts.CoconutCreamPieIV[0];
text_headline.text = desserts.EasySugarCookies[0];
text_headline.text = desserts.ChocolateMeringuePie[0];
text_headline.text = desserts.SweetAndSaltyCaramelApples[0];

//Output for ingredients
text_bigfield.htmlText = desserts.PistachioFluffFruitSalad[1] + "<br>" +  desserts.PistachioFluffFruitSalad[2] + "<br>" + desserts.PistachioFluffFruitSalad[3] + "<br>" + desserts.PistachioFluffFruitSalad[4] + "<br>" + desserts.PistachioFluffFruitSalad[5] + "<br>" + desserts.PistachioFluffFruitSalad[6] + "<br>" + desserts.PistachioFluffFruitSalad[7];
text_bigfield.htmlText = desserts.CoconutCreamPieIV[1] + "<br>" + desserts.CoconutCreamPieIV[2] + "<br>" + desserts.CoconutCreamPieIV[3] + "<br>" + desserts.CoconutCreamPieIV[4] + "<br>" + desserts.CoconutCreamPieIV[5] + "<br>" + desserts.CoconutCreamPieIV[6] + "<br>" + desserts.CoconutCreamPieIV[7] + "<br>" + desserts.CoconutCreamPieIV[8] + "<br>" + desserts.CoconutCreamPieIV[9] + "<br>" + desserts.CoconutCreamPieIV[10] + "<br>" + desserts.CoconutCreamPieIV[11];
text_bigfield.htmlText = desserts.EasySugarCookies[1] + "<br>" + desserts.EasySugarCookies[2] + "<br>" + desserts.EasySugarCookies[3] + "<br>" + desserts.EasySugarCookies[4] + "<br>" + desserts.EasySugarCookies[5] + "<br>" + desserts.EasySugarCookies[6] + "<br>" + desserts.EasySugarCookies[7];
text_bigfield.htmlText = desserts.ChocolateMeringuePie[1] + "<br>" + desserts.ChocolateMeringuePie[2] + "<br>" + desserts.ChocolateMeringuePie[3] + "<br>" + desserts.ChocolateMeringuePie[4] + "<br>" + desserts.ChocolateMeringuePie[5] + "<br>" + desserts.ChocolateMeringuePie[6] + "<br>" + desserts.ChocolateMeringuePie[7] + "<br>" + desserts.ChocolateMeringuePie[8] + "<br>" + desserts.ChocolateMeringuePie[9] + "<br>" + desserts.ChocolateMeringuePie[10];
text_bigfield.htmlText = desserts.SweetAndSaltyCaramelApples[1] + "<br>" + desserts.SweetAndSaltyCaramelApples[2] + "<br>" + desserts.SweetAndSaltyCaramelApples[3] + "<br>" + desserts.SweetAndSaltyCaramelApples[4] + "<br>" + desserts.SweetAndSaltyCaramelApples[5] + "<br>" + desserts.SweetAndSaltyCaramelApples[6] + "<br>" + desserts.SweetAndSaltyCaramelApples[7];

btn_pistachio.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pistachiotext);
btn_coconut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK coconuttext);
btn_cookie.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK cookietext);
btn_chocolate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK chocolatetext);
btn_caramelapple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK caramelappletext);

function pistachiotext(event:MouseEvent){
text_headline.text[0]
text_bigfield.htmlText[1]
}

function coconuttext(event:MouseEvent){
text_headline.text[0]
text_bigfield.htmlText[2]
}
function cookietext(event:MouseEvent){
text_headline.text[0]
text_bigfield.htmlText[3]
}
function chocolatetext(event:MouseEvent){
text_headline.text[0]
text_bigfield.htmlText[4]
}
function caramelappletext(event:MouseEvent){
text_headline.text[0]
text_bigfield.htmlText[5]
}
```

I know there's something funky with the functions but I can't quite figure what. I've been googling around and looking through my book(that my teacher required and never taught from). The fact that he changed up how we were doing this and didn't really go over this new way has really thrown me off.

with the way everything is typed now I'm getting compiler errors:

Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 31 1084:Syntax error: expecting rightparen before coconuttext.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 32 1084:Syntax error: expecting rightparen before cookietext.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 33 1084:Syntax error: expecting rightparen before chocolatetext.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 31 1084:Syntax error: expecting rightparen before caramelappletext.

Edit: I am now getting the output error:
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 1 not found on String and there is no default value. at KaraRichardsonRecipesDigitalA1_fla::MainTimeline/pistachiotext()

what does this error mean?

Answer (score 2):

You need to place a **,** between the parameters of the functions, like:

```
 btn_pistachio.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pistachiotext);
 btn_coconut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, coconuttext);
 btn_cookie.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cookietext);
 btn_chocolate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chocolatetext);
 btn_caramelapple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, caramelappletext);
```

Comment: Ok that helped quite a bit. There's text now when I run it! :D Now I'm getting output errors whenever I click on my buttons:

"ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 0 not found on String and there is no default value.
 at KaraRichardsonRecipesDigitalA1_fla::MainTimeline/pistachiotext()
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 0 not found on String and there is no default value.
 at KaraRichardsonRecipesDigitalA1_fla::MainTimeline/pistachiotext()"

Comment: you can't reference string in actionscript with [].. the error message says which line has the problem, and wich function. Its pistachitext() function.

Comment: also, try to google.. you're asking questions every minute?? you're definately new to as3, so you should first check out some tutorials, like gotoandlearn.com to get started

Comment: I honestly don't know, I've been just typing out different things that worked on a previous assignment that we did in class. that assignment in class was basically the same as what I'm doing now except with a different theme and he's changed how he wants us to do some of the scripting last second.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm asking so much. As you said, I am very new to all this and my teacher hasn't bothered to go into too much depth..at least not enough for me

Comment: What are you trying to do here - 'text_headline.text[0]'. text_headline.text is a string, if your trying to access a character of the string (such as 'U' from the string 'SUPERMAN') you want to use the getCharAt() function. Even then though, you're not assigning or modifying it in those event handlers.

Comment: I'd also suggest walking through some basic tutorials, or maybe hitting up your teacher in an email, so they can walk you through what you don't understand.

Comment: Can someone turn this into a chat so I don't get in trouble for discussing everything in the comments. I need a ton of help. I don't have time for tutorials

Comment: Also, all of the tutorials I've found are wanting me to use a different coding than what my teacher is wanting us to do.

Comment: than you should tried to listen more carefully.. this is not a 'we'll do  your homework' forum..

Comment: I wasn't asking anyone to do my homework for me. My teacher didn't really explain any of this, everyone in my class was struggling. I just needed you all to explain what you were talking about was wrong with my code in more depth because my teacher never explained how or why anything worked the way it did. He basically just put it on the projector and said, "here's the code, type it." I'm done with my work now anyway but I would still like these functions explained to me because I *want* to understand this stuff. I wouldn't be going to college for this if I didn't.